# Dynamic forms sortable using angular cdk drag and drop

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a google forms clone, here's what it looks like

[image]

when i drag first form down, this happen

[image]

mat-select value not changing, and checkbox option gone. for drop function i have this

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    this.list = this.surveyForm.get("sectionQuestions")["controls"];
    console.log(this.list);
    moveItemInArray(this.list, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    this.questionFormArray.controls[event.currentIndex]['controls']['display_order']
      .setValue(event.currentIndex + 1);
    this.questionFormArray.controls.forEach((category, index) => {
      (category as FormGroup).controls['display_order'].setValue(index + 1);
    });
  }
```

did i miss something? did by setting the display_order is not enough? any thoughts would be helpful

Comment: Might be a design issue. If you create an abstract control that is just a json description of what you want then dropping the json is rendered into a Angular component that interprets and renders

Comment: well do you have an example? related post/tutorial maybe?

Comment: on my json it's working fine, but on the view it's odd seeing something like that

Comment: Here's an article on Json as a Dsl. https://dev.to/jwp/when-a-json-file-becomes-a-dsl-2h4b

Comment: what is refactoring means there?

Comment: You're on right track just set break points on drop and single step.

Comment: single step? i just heard that, what do you mean by that?

Comment: It means if json content properties need changing it's not the same as renaming symbols in JavaScript where every instance is changed in every reference.

Comment: actually i'm trying to mimic this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asevei-kzhw4x, but mine is more complex than that

Comment: Ok they are simply rearranging the json. This means the Angular rendering renders based on Json. Exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: yes actually my json is doing exactly like they have to, but idk why it's happening with that forms